# Asp.net MVC 3: Model comes empty in the controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

I've a form in which I only have to choose between several entities.

So here is what I've done:

Created a view Model:

```
    public class EntityChooserModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Entity> AvailableEntities { get; set; }
        public int SelectedId;
    }
```

I've two actions in the controller, one with [HTTPPost], one without. In both I have a "SessionUserData", which is session data, bound through data model binding.

```
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult EntityChooser(SessionUserData sessionData)
        {
            List<Entity> entities = _userStore.GetRoles(User.Identity.Name).Select(ur => ur.Entity).ToList();


            Entity entity = sessionData.IdCurrentEntity != null ? entities.Where(e => e.Id == sessionData.IdCurrentEntity).First() : entities.First();

            return View(new EntityChooserModel() { SelectedId = entity.Id, AvailableEntities = entities });
        }
```

.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EntityChooser( EntityChooserModel model, SessionUserData sessionData, String returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Entity entity = _userStore.GetRoles(User.Identity.Name).Select(ur => ur.Entity).Where(e => e.Id == model.SelectedId).First();
            sessionData.IdCurrentEntity = entity.Id;
            RedirectToDefaultPage(returnUrl);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

And the strongly typed view:

```
@model My.Full.Namespace.EntityChooserModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EntityChooser";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}
<div id="login-wrapper">
    <div id="title">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="login">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EntityChooser", "Auth", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ChooseFormId" }))
        {            
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Loggin error")
            <div>
                <span>Choose an entity:</span>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.AvailableEntities, "Id", "Name"))
            </div>
            <p class="right-aligned">
                <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('ChooseFormId').submit();" class="adm-button">
                    <span class="next-btn"><span>Select</span></span></a>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" style="display: none" />
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I receive the data in the second model, I've an empty object. The collection is empty, and the id is set to the default value(0).

What is wrong? I can't find out what I missed on this one.

It's the first time I do an mvc form which isn't `ForModel()`, and the first time I've to use a dropdownlist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only input element that your `<form>` contains is a single drop down list which sends only the selected value to the server when POSTed. This explains why your `AvailableEntities` collection property is empty.

As far as why the `SelectedId` field is empty, it is because you have defined it as a **field** and not as a **property**. The default model binder works only with properties. So if you want it to be populated you must define it as a property:

```
public int SelectedId { get; set; }
```

As far as the `AvailableEntities` property is concerned you could populate it from your repository in the POST action using the selected id.

Comment: GOD LIKE! I don't know why I put a field here instead of a property! Thank you so much!